# The Id column get a value of None in py2neo.ogm

Tags: py2neo

I'm working with the interface py2neo to access the neo4j database out of python. I want to used the autogenerated Id column in an OGM model as a property. But my idea doesn't work. Please look a the example:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
from py2neo.ogm import GraphObject, Property, RelatedTo, RelatedFrom

class Material(GraphObject):
    id = Property()
    name = Property()
    description = Property()
```

I insert the values into the system:

```
mat_f01 = Node('Material', name='F01', description='Fert Product 01')
mat_f02 = Node('Material', name='F02', description='Fert Product 02')
```

In the neo4j browser the record are displayed as followed - with the id column:

```
<id>:178 description: Fert Product 02 name: F02
```

If I look to the same records in flask the Id column contains the value None. It should contain 177 and 178.

```
description             id      name
Fert Product 01 Fert    None    F01 
Fert Product 03 Fert    None    F03
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The node ID has no correlation with the properties on that node. It is more of an internal attribute, closer to the address of a variable than an auto-generated ID. It is exposed by Neo4j as a convenience but should not be used for anything that requires a stable node reference as it can't provide those guarantees of stability.

If you want a unique identifier *property* then I recommend a UUID4 hex string instead. You can generate one of these in Python via the uuid module, and it should be guaranteed unique for all practical purposes.